# How to mark an image?

Tags: image

How can I place a mark, like a cross-hair (to suggest "X marks the spot") and a text label associated with it, at a particular position on an image (mine in particular is `Colorize`d)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a simple way:

```
Show[
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}],
    Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{3 \[Pi]/2, -1}],
    Black, Text["Minimum", {3 \[Pi]/2, -.8}]}]]
```

[image]

### Edit

If you have an image created with Colorize you can apply the same method. In the example below img is the image you obtain by taking the first example given in the Help under `Colorize`.

```
Show[
   img,
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{20, 100}],
   White, Text["California", {30, 90}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: My image is created with `Colorize` and this gives `Raster data contains 0 values per pixel; 3 or 4 are required with ColorFunction->RGBColor`, even though it displays fine without the text.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the `Drawing Tools` palette to annotate an image interactively. It can be invoked in three ways:

1. Selecting `Drawing Tools` from the `Graphics` menu
2. Using the short-cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or
3. Using the right-click context menu on a graphics object:

[image: context menu -- drawing tools]

For a detailed tutorial on the Drawing Tools palette see [Interactive Graphics Palette](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html).
The following image from the tutorial summarizes the functions in the palette:

[image]

Usage example: palette states and before and after appearance of the image using the same image in vucko's answer:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another approach:

```
anXtoMarkTheSpot = Graphics[{
  White,
  Line[{{0,10}, {0, -10}}], 
  Line[{{-10,0}, {10, 0}}], 
  Text[Style["the Spot",14, Bold, White, 
      TextAlignment->Left],{20,5}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 80];

treasureMap = Colorize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Aerial2"}]];

ImageCompose[treasureMap, anXtoMarkTheSpot, {60,40}]
```

[image: treasure map]