# How can I superimpose points or disks on an image at specified coordinates?

Tags: image-processing, image

I have a TIFF image of 640 x 640 pixels, over which I would like to plot a list of points or disks of small radius.

I have been testing different alternatives and I found ImageCompose command.

```
ImageCompose[image, {Graphics[{PointSize[.009], Black, Point[{0, 0}]}], .6}, {600, 600}]
```

This places a point at location `{600, 600}` relative to the origin at the left-bottom of the image, but if I set a point close to the right edge of the image, say `{635, 600}`, the point is in the frame but there is no image behind it, because the image is not showing all its pixels. It appears that the first 20-25 pixels of the image and the last 20-25 pixels of the image are invisible.

When I tick the image it shows the image at the center of the frame and two blank vertical spaces at right and left of the image.

Two questions:

- Does there exist any option or command I could use to show the full image, i.e., the entire 640 x 640 pixels?
- How can I superimpose a list of points (e.g., 40 points) at specified pixel coordinates within the same image.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3725/685

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 3):

`Show` will display `Image` and `Graphics` simultaneously, placing both in the same system coordinate - this is why it is convenient in your case.

```
i = ImageTake[  ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Girl3"}], {60, 160}, {100, 200}];
Show[i, Graphics[{Red, Opacity[.5], PointSize[.005], 
   Point[Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 100}, {j, 100}], 1]]}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**Answer to comment**

Let's see in detail what is happening. This is simple 3px by 3px image:

```
i = Image[HilbertMatrix[3]]
```

[image]

By controlling an offset `0 < d < 1` you can place your points precisely around your pixels. For example this proves that with `d = -.5` **all 9 points are inside the image** on the centers of pixels. Nothing gets out. You can control offset as you wish.

```
d = -.5;
Show[i, Graphics[{Red, Opacity[.5], PointSize[.1], 
   Point[Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}], 1] + d]}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Very straightforward solution. I still have the two blank strips at the right and left of my image. If I place a point Point[{5, 55}], then it appears with white background. Should I export the image with some option to remove the white between the image and the frame of the image?

Comment: @PLM Does `PlotRangePadding -> 0` help?

Comment: I have tested like Show[im, {Graphics[{PointSize[.009], Black, Point[{5, 55}]}]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0] and still is outside the image. How can I make the image full visible?

Comment: Perfect Thank you very much

Comment: @PLM I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is `HighlightImage`, a neat addition for version 9, any use here? It takes a list of coordinates, and various highlighting techniques as options:

```
i = ImageAdjust[
  ImageResize[
     ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], {640, 640}], {-0.5, -0.1}];

HighlightImage[i, {{600, 600}, {635, 600}}, Method -> {"DiskMarkers", 6}]
```

[image: mandrill]